# how to fix image on Devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

gap app  getting output image sliding but it's come like  with scrolling but i want fit to Screen on any Mobile like(4,5 inches)
here's bit of code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.js"></script>

<style>
.caption {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: none
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 15;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: -2;
  margin-top:-70px;
  max-width: none;
  }
img {
  max-width: 100%;  
  height: auto
     }
.one{ float:right}
 html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #container {
                width: inherit;
                height: inherit;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                        }

</style>
<body>
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="container">
     <img src="images/1 copy.jpg" alt=""></br>
     <div  class="caption"> <font color="white">Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd</br> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white" ><span class="one">skip</span></font></a></div>

</div>

<div id="container">
    <img src="images/2 copy.jpg" alt=""></br>
    <div class="caption"><font color="white" >First Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd</br> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <img src="images/3 copy.jpg" alt=""></br>
    <div class="caption"><font color="white" >three Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd</br> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <img src="images/4 copy.jpg" alt=""></br>
    <div class="caption"><font color="white" >fourth Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd</br> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
<script>


$(function() {
    $(".slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
        var currentSlide = $('.slideshow > div:visible:first'),
            nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        currentSlide.fadeOut(2000)
        nextSlide.fadeIn(2000);

        if ((currentSlide.index() + 1) == 4) {


       Redirect();

        }
    },  2000);
    function Redirect() {
    window.location="https://www.google.co.in";
}
});

</script>
</html>
```

This code output is image automatically sliding but my problem is image come with scroll 
i want image fit to Screen any devices 
So Please give me any idea

Comment: You would need to provide a link to initialized responsiveslides.js plus show us which images were used in your example. Your current example is not enough.

Comment: @Gajotres thanks for Reply http://responsiveslides.com/ i downloaded responsiveslides.js form This Link  i need any image with these dimensions 1081*1921 fit to screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completely redesigned your code, mainly because you've included jQuery Mobile without using correct jQuery Mobile syntax inside your HTML.

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .caption {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2000;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-shadow: none
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        /*margin: -2;
        margin-top:-70px;*/
        max-width: none;
    }
    img {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .one{ 
        float:right
    }
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .ui-content {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });

    $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
        setHeight();
    });
    
    function setHeight() {
        $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-content').height(getRealContentHeight());
        $.mobile.activePage.find('img').height(getRealContentHeight()-4);   
    }

    function getRealContentHeight() {
        var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
        var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
        var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
        var viewport_height = $(window).height();
        
        var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight() -2;
        if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
            content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
        } 
        return content_height;
    }
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">            
    <div data-role="content" class="slideshow">
        <div id="container">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" height="100%" width="auto"/><br/>
            <div  class="caption"> <font color="white">Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a></div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="container">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="caption"><font color="white" >First Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="container">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="caption"><font color="white" >three Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="container">
            <img src="4.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="caption"><font color="white" >fourth Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>


$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(".slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
        var currentSlide = $('.slideshow > div:visible:first'),
            nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        currentSlide.fadeOut(1)
        nextSlide.fadeIn(2000);

        if ((currentSlide.index() + 1) == 4) {


       Redirect();

        }
    },  2000);
    function Redirect() {
        window.location="https://www.google.co.in";
    }
});

</script>
</html>
```

- I have used 4 dummy 1080*1920 images to test this example
- Because you are usinh jQuery Mobile your code is now wrapped inside:

  ```
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
  ```
- It is not enough to set 100% height to your image when working with jQuery Mobile, that's why I am using function getRealContentHeight to get correct content height
- Content height is calculated during pageshow event because that is only time when jQuery Mobile can calculate correct content height
- fadeOut is se to 1 because while old image is fadding out it is still showing thus pusshing next image below, which was a reason why second slider was showing in the first place.

Comment: Thank it's working nice but when check my mobile width problem like(it showing white space on left side image )

Comment: This is because I set img width to auto. I wanted to preserve image width/height aspect ratio. You can always set img width to 100%. <img src="1.jpg" alt="" height="100%" width="100%"/>

Comment: thank for reply i have one issue when run my friend mobile working nice but while sliding images,i am getting white screen before image loading

Comment: This is a common jQuery Mobile problem. Correct page height can only be calculate correctly during pageshow event. But what to do before pageshow triggers? Usually it is fix with some kind of overlay image.

Comment: Just add it to body, put some kind of logo onto it, or loader gif and hide it on pageshow event, just before slider starts to slide.

Comment: @Gajotress i don't have idea on hide loader gif can u tell me how to add loader gif  to body and How to call that event